# exported apk showing activities when installed

Tags: android

I have exported an app with 3 activities (main, splash and another activity called "about") to an apk file. It works fine when tested on the emulator. After uploading to the Play Store and then downloading to my own phone, it installs fine on my phone. Good so far. However, the apk doesn't appear packaged - it's showing the separate activities and not starting with the splash screen as it did in the emulator. What could be the problem? It exported with no errors. When I was exporting, I gave the apk a name that was different than the package name in the manifest. Would this cause the problem? Here is the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.spinner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Thank you for looking.

Comment: You're mixing up a lot of terms and confusing the whole thing.  You don't "export" to an APK.  You build an apk which is nothing more than your compiled code plus resources, libraries etc zipped up.  Building an APK does not change your code so, if your code is not working, the problem is in your code.  You then say it shows "separate activities".  What does this mean?  You can only show one activity at a time so I guess that your only problem is that the splash screen is not showing.  Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Simon, yes, this is what I mean. I'm just saying that I used Export Android Application and figured that that's what I was doing. No worries. I'm just excited that something I made is working! :) The code works in the emulator as I want it to (splash->main, etc.) When I installed on my device (both by using my device as an emulator and downloading directly, the activities show up in the application menu, not as one app in a singular apk file. In other words, I see a launcher icon for each activity instead of one launcher icon for the app that starts the splash and transitions to main.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This intent-filter

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

tells Android launcher app to show icon associated with Activity this filter is attached to on its Launcher screen. When corresponding icon is tapped by user, launcher app starts that activity and your code is executed. You **usually** want one entry point in your application so edit your Manifest file and ensure only one Activity element uses it. In your case, I guess leave it for `SplashActivity` and remove from others. It should look like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.spinner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AboutActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I'd also get rid of `android:label` from `<activity>` elements (just leave for `<application>`)

Comment: Hi WebnetMobile, OK, I see what happened from your explanation. Cripes. Why would Eclipse generate that launcher line for each activity for a multiple activity project, out of curiosity? I guess it's something I'll have to watch for and edit. This is my first attempt at a multiple activity project and loved doing it! Thanks for the hints and showing me what I should look for here. It's always a good day when you learn something.

Comment: I suspect it was you,  not Eclipse :-) it did once when you create project and then you copied it once you added new activities